# Single function from multiple ng-show functions in a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a couple of functions that I've written in Angular to display multiple ng-show attributes on a page via scopes. I attempted to put all three into a single function using if else statements, but I couldn't get the function to fire for a second time. I'm wondering if there's a way to do this in a single function, and what the best practice for this sort of functionality is.

JS Fiddle is here - http://jsfiddle.net/ezy_/01L050mr/2/

Here's the JS that's currently spread across 3 different functions.

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

function AppCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.skillsState = false;

  $scope.rolesState = false;

  $scope.qualsState = false;

  $scope.skillsStateTrigger = function() {
    $scope.skillsState = true;
    $scope.rolesState = false;
    $scope.qualsState = false;
  };

  $scope.rolesStateTrigger = function() {
    $scope.skillsState = false;
    $scope.rolesState = true;
    $scope.qualsState = false;
  };

  $scope.qualsStateTrigger = function() {
    $scope.skillsState = false;
    $scope.rolesState = false;
    $scope.qualsState = true;
  };
}
```

Do I need a $watch or $apply function to trigger updates if I set the function to fire from a single statesTrigger(resp) function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your refactor. The trick is to use an object to store the 3 states.

js:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

function AppCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.states = {
     skills: false,
     roles: false,
     quals: false
  };

  $scope.trigger_state = function(state) {
    for(var i in $scope.states) {
      $scope.states[i] = (i == state);
    }
  };
}
```

html:

```
<body ng-app="app" class="ng-scope">
  <div class="container ng-scope" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <button ng-click="trigger_state('skills')">Skills</button>
  <button ng-click="trigger_state('roles')">Roles</button>
  <button ng-click="trigger_state('quals')">Quals</button>
  <div class="row" ng-show="states.skills" style="display: none;">
    Skills State Active
  </div>
  <div class="row" ng-show="states.roles" style="display: none;">
    Roles State Active
  </div>
  <div class="row" ng-show="states.quals" style="display: none;">
    Quals State Active
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

In that case it's kinda a bad idea to use 3 states, you could use 1 one variable to store "state" = "mystate" for example (since the states are exclusive).

Answer (score 2):

Have a look here: [updated with 1 function](http://jsfiddle.net/bp8sjuh0/2/)

```js
  $scope.triggerState = function (state) {
    if (state == 'skills') {
      $scope.skillsStateTrigger();
    } else if (state == 'roles') {
      $scope.rolesStateTrigger();
    } else if (state == 'quals') {
      $scope.qualsStateTrigger();
    }
  }
```

```html
  <button ng-click="triggerState('skills')">Skills</button>
  <button ng-click="triggerState('roles')">Roles</button>
  <button ng-click="triggerState('quals')">Quals</button>
```

You can even be more specific in the HTML itself like this: [State variable](http://jsfiddle.net/6qzhf9m3/1/)

```html
<body ng-app="app" class="ng-scope">
  <div class="container ng-scope" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <button ng-click="currentState = 'skills'">Skills</button>
    <button ng-click="currentState = 'roles'">Roles</button>
    <button ng-click="currentState = 'quals'">Quals</button>
    <div class="row" ng-show="currentState == 'skills'" style="display: none;">
      Skills State Active
    </div>
    <div class="row" ng-show="currentState == 'roles'" style="display: none;">
      Roles State Active
    </div>
    <div class="row" ng-show="currentState == 'quals'" style="display: none;">
      Quals State Active
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```